# Is it possible to mock a module and all it's submodules in pytest at once?

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

I am trying to mock a module in pytest and have a lot of functions from that module imported like so:

```
from common.util import funct1, funct2, funct3
from common.shared.utils import some_funct
from common.public.utils import some_other_funct
```

So far I have been using

```
sys.modules['common.util'] = MagicMock()
sys.modules['common.shared.utils'] = MagicMock()
sys.modules['common.public.utils'] = MagicMock()
```

Is there a way to combine all these imports into one line?